# How do I make image fill padding of parent div?

Tags: html, css

I need to get the child div to fill the padding of parent div without removing the padding of parent div.

```
<body>
  <div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
     my image
   </div>
  </div>
```

```
.parent {
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}

.child {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE here](https://jsfiddle.net/9gn6gk69/)

Preferred solutions are either css or html changes, no js.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, but perhaps add some negative margin to the child and then fix it with padding?

```
.child {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 -20px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqvhoy29/)

Comment: Thanks for helping but I need a cleaner solution!

Comment: What do you mean "cleaner"? This is *the* solution based on your requirements.